# What does it mean for a binomial distribution to be normalized over something?

Tags: bayesian, normalization

This is my first post on cross validated (and my first attempt at statistics!) so please let me know if I haven't been clear enough with my question.

So I was learning about Bayesian Parameter Estimation, when I came across this for likelihood:

[image]

[image]

This was immediately followed by the statement "The binomial distribution is normalized over   . Later, we will need to normalize over  ."
I looked up on the internet to see what 'normalization' is and apparently it means shifting the distribution so that are under it becomes 1. What I didn't get, however, is what it means to 'normalize over some value'.

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: It looks a little loose, as I would say $P_N(n \mid \theta) =   \frac{N!}{n!(N-n)!} \theta^n(1-\theta)^{N-n}$ with the likelihood being proportional to that.   You have $\sum\limits_{n=0}^N P_N(n \mid \theta) =1$ summing over $n$ as with a binomial distribution.  But if $n$ is given and the posterior distribution for $\theta$ given $n$ is proportional to $\theta^n(1-\theta)^{N-n}$  then you have $\int\limits_{\theta=0}^1 \frac{(N+1)!}{n!(N-n)!} \theta^n(1-\theta)^{N-n} \, d\theta=1$ integrating over $\theta$ as with a Beta distribution, which is not the same

Comment: $\theta$ can potentially take any real value from $0$ to $1$ so does not have a binomial distribution

Comment: The "over $n$" is a somewhat unusual way of indicating $n$ represents the values of the random variable.

Comment: Normalised over $n$ means multiplied by the correct constant for the density (in $n$) to be a probability density (or pmf since $n$ is an integer).

Comment: Those are helpful comments, thank you!